# Can we write macro in C# for MS-Word

Tags: c#, vba, visual-studio, ms-word

Can we write macro for MS-Word in C#?
If it is possible, please prefer some references website and resource.

- such as where is it's IDE?
- How can publish or interpret run that macros?
- And prefer a simple example for doing a task with macro, that wrote
  in C#

According [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a9dt54a.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1), I guessed it may possible.

Comment: You can write macros in VBA within Word's IDE, or automation code in C# from Visual Studio (which is what your link refers to)

Comment: I familiar with VBA. what about C#? Please visit my above link in post.

Comment: Google for *c# word automation* E.g. https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/CSAutomateWord-f422cae5 - This is using the same object model that is exposed to VBA within word but in c# outside word.

Comment: I thought Microsoft presented some macros in C#, In [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a9dt54a.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) link.

Comment: The link shows *document-level customization* vs. *VSTO-Addin*. The former embeds a .NET customization into a single document (or template) and the latter gets installed as a MS Office AddIn. Chose whichever best fits your use case.

Comment: Help. "Stackoverflow" banned me from asking questions, because of this negative votes. Please say me why this question had collected 3 negative vote? Please help me to get out of question ban.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write an Add-in in C# using Visual Studio and Visual Studio Tools for Office that will add functionality to Word, but you can't write a "macro" really.  If what you're asking is whether there's a way to go into the VBA IDE and change a setting so that you can write the code in C# as opposed to VBA, no.  There's not a way to do that.

You'll need Visual Studio.  In older versions, VSTO only came with Professional edition or but I've heard that has changed although I'm not sure.

Here's a starting point for using VSTO:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442946.aspx

Comment: Please take a look [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a9dt54a.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1). Microsoft preferred some examples for macro in C#.

Comment: I did look there.  If you read the page carefully you'll see that the code examples apply to VSTO Add-Ins.  Those are components you build in Visual Studio and then incorporate into Word docs, or Excel workbooks or whatever else.  The examples on that page use classes from the Namespace  Microsoft.Office.Interop or Microsoft.Office.Tools.  You still need Visual Studio.  It's a different thing than building a macro.

Comment: Help. "Stackoverflow" banned me from asking questions, because of this negative votes. Please say me why this question had collected 3 negative vote? Please help me to get out of question ban.

Comment: Edit your question to reflect on that is more on topic. Do a little more research and formulate a more specific question.

Comment: I was banned from asking question. why they rate me 3 negative?

Comment: MR Stewart, I edited and reviewed my questions, and presented exact revision of them, that I can. (about a week ago). but they're stay in negative votes and I banned from asking question. What's problems of my question? I searched for them before and can reach my answer, thus renewed questions. How can I solve problems and ban asking questions limitation?

Comment: @mgae2m We think we are somewhat higher humans here. So we replace some particular negative words into negative votes. That's it. It's just that simple. Surely, this comment just violates that principle. Are we really higher? You can surely decide.